# How to correctly make a large limited distance between widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need help. Tell me how to correctly add a limited empty space (as in the screenshot) between the `2500 widget` and the `buttons` that are at the very bottom. It is necessary to add exactly the limited distance so that I can use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget. And so that on different screen sizes this empty distance changes according to the screens of the device. I will be grateful for help.

```
Widget _child() => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Column(
          
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 121.0),
            BackStepWidget(
              text: 'Balance: $coins',
              textStyle: constants.Styles.largeHeavyTextStyleWhite,
            ),
            const Text(
              'Buy JoinCoins',
              style: constants.Styles.bigHeavyTextStyleWhite,
            ),
            const Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'),
            ),
            const CoinsCounterWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

[image]

Comment: try using the spacer() widget inside the column between your widgets, as it expands as much as it can

Comment: And if I need to add SingleChildScrollView to the page, then Spacer will cause an error, since there will be an unlimited height?

Answer (score 0):

For limited height based on screen, you need to get the size of the screen, you can use `MediaQuery` but I prefer using `LayoutBuilder`.

Use `LayoutBuilder` as top/first widget and use its constraints to get size. I am using on `body` to avoid mixing others spaces,

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Column(
        children: [

          Text("top items"),
          SizedBox(height: constraints.maxHeight*.2,) // 20% height 
          // others widgets
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

More about [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html).

Comment: I understand correctly, with the help of your solution, I can constantly change the size of the empty space depending on the screen size? And thus there will be a column of the fixed size?

Comment: I just need to have an empty space between the top widgets and the bottom buttons fixed so that I can add a SingleChildScrollView, and that the distance between the top widgets and the bottom buttons changes on different screen sizes.

Comment: try to put `LayoutBuilder` at top level, before using `SingleChildScrollView` this should work as I understand, you can try yourself